# disable RADIUS for Cisco 2500 wireless controller

Tags: cisco, wifi

I have a [Cisco 2500 wireless controller](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps11630/tsd_products_support_series_home.html) and four lightweight access points. I want to use the controller to manage a wireless network secured by WPA only, without using RADIUS or anything else. We'll handle the authentication using a captive portal behind the access points.
However, it seems like the controller's default security policy requires a RADIUS server and I can't find out how to switch the policy off. The documentation assumes I'm in an environment which needs heavy-duty security and the use case is actually a small charity/business with much less stringent security requirements.

How do I disable the complicated security policy and instead run a simple one that just uses WPA?

Comment: please use more descriptive titles for your questions. i will edit this one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WLAN settings dictate the authentication protocol.  Sounds like you have 8021.X enabled.  L2 security should just be WPA2-PSK.  With that setting, AAA Override or RADIUS servers defined globally on the WLC should not matter.  (I'm basing this on a 5508 and am assuming it's not too different on the 2500).